# how can i read a protein sequence without using any package ?

Tags: r

I have a sequence looks like this

```
>sp|O00330|ODPX_HUMAN Pyruvate dehydrogenase protein X component, mitochondrial OS=Homo sapiens GN=PDHX PE=1 SV=3
MAASWRLGCDPRLLRYLVGFPGRRSVGLVKGALGWSVSRGANWRWFHSTQWLRGDPIKIL
MPSLSPTMEEGNIVKWLKKEGEAVSAGDALCEIETDKAVVTLDASDDGILAKIVVEEGSK
NIRLGSLIGLIVEEGEDWKHVEIPKDVGPPPPVSKPSEPRPSPEPQISIPVKKEHIPGTL
RFRLSPAARNILEKHSLDASQGTATGPRGIFTKEDALKLVQLKQTGKITESRPTPAPTAT
PTAPSPLQATAGPSYPRPVIPPVSTPGQPNAVGTFTEIPASNIRRVIAKRLTESKSTVPH
AYATADCDLGAVLKVRQDLVKDDIKVSVNDFIIKAAAVTLKQMPDVNVSWDGEGPKQLPF
IDISVAVATDKGLLTPIIKDAAAKGIQEIADSVKALSKKARDGKLLPEEYQGGSFSISNL
GMFGIDEFTAVINPPQACILAVGRFRPVLKLTEDEEGNAKLQQRQLITVTMSSDSRVVDD
ELATRFLKSFKANLENPIRLA
```

can be downloaded from here 
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/aed8fcc410b6794316430513676e8a82

I know I can load it into R using different packages for example

```
install.packages("CHNOSZ") 
library(CHNOSZ)
myr <- read.fasta(example.fasta)
```

or

```
library("Biostrings")
s = readDNAStringSet("example.fasta")
```

Since I am having conflict with these packages (they don't properly import my pasta). I need to load it without using any file

I did used the following

```
example <- read.table("path to the data/example.fasta",comment.char="" )
```

this load it but put it in several lines, I want it all in one and not several lines

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Do you want the first row (starting with `>sp...`) or just the string starting with `MAAS...`?

Comment: @Weihuang Wong the first row is not so important in sequences but does it matter ?

Comment: Well... I know nothing about DNA sequences.  I'm just wondering what the output you have in mind is.

Comment: You can directly call functions using "package name"::"function read.fasta(example.fasta) ", like this:`CHNOSZ::read.fasta(example.fasta)`. This would be a workaround to you conflict issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try `readLines` and `paste(..., collapse = "")`.

```
# Here, `con` is a URL, but it can also be a filename
con <- "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/aed8fcc410b6794316430513676e8a82/raw/3a18ea69fea90c8c74b82777f6eef5c840a46581/example.fasta"

data <- readLines(con)
list(description = data[1], 
     sequence = paste(data[-1], collapse = ""))
# $description
# [1] ">sp|O00330|ODPX_HUMAN Pyruvate dehydrogenase protein X component, mitochondrial OS=Homo sapiens GN=PDHX PE=1 SV=3"

# $sequence
# [1] "MAASWRLGCDPRLLRYLVGFPGRRSVGLVKGALGWSVSRGANWRWFHSTQWLRGDPIKILMPSLSPTMEEGNIVKWLKKEGEAVSAGDALCEIETDKAVVTLDASDDGILAKIVVEEGSKNIRLGSLIGLIVEEGEDWKHVEIPKDVGPPPPVSKPSEPRPSPEPQISIPVKKEHIPGTLRFRLSPAARNILEKHSLDASQGTATGPRGIFTKEDALKLVQLKQTGKITESRPTPAPTATPTAPSPLQATAGPSYPRPVIPPVSTPGQPNAVGTFTEIPASNIRRVIAKRLTESKSTVPHAYATADCDLGAVLKVRQDLVKDDIKVSVNDFIIKAAAVTLKQMPDVNVSWDGEGPKQLPFIDISVAVATDKGLLTPIIKDAAAKGIQEIADSVKALSKKARDGKLLPEEYQGGSFSISNLGMFGIDEFTAVINPPQACILAVGRFRPVLKLTEDEEGNAKLQQRQLITVTMSSDSRVVDDELATRFLKSFKANLENPIRLA"
```